# MVC3 Parameterised Routing gives 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a URL: `http://localhost/Details/1` but getting a 404. So far I have done:

**Global.asax**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace RMA
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Details",
                "Details/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Details", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

**DetailsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What's the point in the second route if your controller is called "Details" anyway? Particularly as nothing will ever hit it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The order is important. Here the Default route match the url before the Details route

Comment: @fred so I put non Default on Top? it then mess with Home Page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the order is important. Go from specific to general on the mappings. Details-specfic mappings should be first.

But I don't think it'd work after that, either, unless you have an action called "1" on the Details controller. ;)

If you want to map it directly to the controller with no action, try something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Details",
                "Details/{id}",
                new { controller = "Details", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Not working.. I added this one after Default one, still giving 404. I am accessing URL like: http://localhost:3480/Details/6

Comment: You added it after the Default one? Well, yeah. See my answer again.